# Python SDK installation error

Tags: python, predictionio

I tried to install Python SDK, using the following command:

`pip install predictionio`

```
but I'm getting this error:



 Collecting predictionio
    Collecting pytz>=2014.2 (from predictionio)
      Using cached pytz-2017.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    Installing collected packages: pytz, predictionio
      Found existing installation: pytz 2013.7
        Uninstalling pytz-2013.7:
    Exception:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
        status = self.run(options, args)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
        prefix=options.prefix_path,
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 778, in install
        requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 754, in uninstall
        paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
        renames(path, new_path)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames
        shutil.move(old, new)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 299, in move
        copytree(src, real_dst, symlinks=True)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 208, in copytree
        raise Error, errors
```

Also, with easy_install predictionIO, it doesn't gives any error, but then the predictionio module can not be found.

Comment: Have you tried with `sudo`?

Comment: Yes, but I also got this exception:`Collecting predictionio
Collecting pytz>=2014.2 (from predictionio)
  Downloading pytz-2017.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (484kB
Installing collected packages: pytz, predictionio
  Found existing installation: pytz 2013.7
    Uninstalling pytz-2013.7:
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  `..................